# Install CA on android Using Intent not works on android 2.3

Tags: android, https, ca

I am trying to add a CA certificate programatically in a HTC Desire S device Android version 2.3.5 and HTC Sense version 3.0.

I am using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.credentials.INSTALL");
intent.putExtra("name","testCA");
intent.putExtra("CERT", bytes);
startActivityForResult(intent, CA_CERT_ADDED);
startActivityForResult(intent, CA_CERTIFICATE_ADDED);
```

When I run the code the dialog appears stating that I am installing a CA certificate, Toast message also display which says CA is successfully install.

But on activity result i also got 0( Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)  against resultCode.

On other types of devices S3 with android 4.0 its works fine.

Has anyone else ever come across this before and is there a solution to it.

Comment: Still have this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This method works with me , try it 
    public static void exportCACertToUserStore(Context context){

```
    String ACTION_INSTALL = "android.credentials.INSTALL";
    String EXTRA_CERTIFICATE = "CERT";


    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.certinstaller","com.android.certinstaller.CertInstallerMain");
    try {
        String keystoreCAExportFullPath = PreferenceUtils.getCAExportFilePath(context.getApplicationContext());
        File caExportFile = new File(keystoreCAExportFullPath);
        byte[] result = new byte[(int) caExportFile.length()];
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(caExportFile);
        in.read(result);
        in.close();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, result);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: how will you get this cert back?